# Проверка переменной на валидность UTF-8

Tags: php

```
function getPassword() {// Возвращает валидный пароль
    global $length; // Длинная пароля
    $glength = $length;                                                                         
    $password = getRandomPassword(); // Пароль
        do {
           $password = getRandomPassword();
            $test_lentgh = iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $glength; //Проверка пароля на длинну
        } while($test_lentgh);
    return $password;
```

Функция берет пароль и возвращает только те, которые соответствуют заданной длинне.
Как можно в цикл запихать проверку на валидность?
Требования к паролю такие: `Минимум 1 Спецсимвол, и минимум 2 цифры.`
в пароле есть кирилица.

Comment: пример того что возвращает функция:БАДЬЯ_!ЛЕЧИ*^ , 72иль$дорога@

Comment: Желательно видеть полный код, а так, рекомендую использовать [Хеширование паролей](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.password.php), а на проверку длины, использовать `strlen` или `mb_strlen` на этапе хеширование, тогда не придется делать такие костыли, как делаете вы..

Answer (score 0):

Вот реализация которая вас интересует:

```
function getPassword($length)
    while (true) {
        $password = getRandomPassword();
        if (iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $length) continue;
        if (/* не удовлетворяет условию 2 */) continue;

        // если все условия выполнены, то возвращаем результат
        return password; 
    }
}
```

Но в целом такой подход плохой, потому как результат можно никогда так и не получить. Лучше переделать функцию `getRandomPassword()` так, что бы она генерировала именно то, что вам нужно